# AngularJS ng-class adding class but not removing it on change

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I have a text input within an ng-repeat. When I click on the input I'm attaching a date picker and triggering a change() on the input when the date is selected.

```
$(this).val(picker.startDate.format(datePickerOutputFormat)).change();
```

This works and AngularJS scope picks up the change. I have a span on the page that is bound to the date value so I can see this changing.

On the input, I want to highlight null dates using ng-class with the following.

```
<input type="text"
  class="form-control single-date-input"
  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
  ng-model="demoInRepeat.date"
  ng-class="{ 'invalid-input' : null == demoInRepeat.date }">
```

This works fine, until I manual edit the input value and delete the date. If I pick the date off the date picker again the invalid-input class remains even though the value update on both the input and on the span I'm using to show the scope is changing.

Even if I display the evaluated value of the ng-class condition, this shows true/false as expected.

```
{{ null == demoInRepeat.date }}
```

I would expect the invalid-input class to be removed once the date is re-selected. Any ideas?

Using AngularJS v1.5.8

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background and finally kick jQuery. =)

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution helps to remove invalid-input class once the date is re-selected. create one more class called **valid-input** and add CSS for that and you will be done.

```
<input type="text"
  class="form-control single-date-input"
  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
  ng-model="demoInRepeat.date"
  ng-class="{ 'invalid-input' : null == demoInRepeat.date , 'valid-input' : null != demoInRepeat.date }">
```

Comment: @user1107685 I will appreciate if you got the solution, Yes If you want to apply CSS on some condition then this solution is better.

Comment: sorry I thought that worked but it was actually getting stuck on valid-input and no longer showing invalid-input when I made the input invalid again.

Comment: can you please create plunker for this, I will help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with a workaround that doesn't use ng-class.

I changed this...

```
<input type="text"
  class="form-control single-date-input"
  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
  ng-model="demoInRepeat.date"
  ng-class="{ 'invalid-input' : null == demoInRepeat.date }">
```

to this

```
<input type="text"
  class="form-control single-date-input {{ null == demoInRepeat.date ? 'invalid-input' : '' }}"
  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
  ng-model="demoInRepeat.date">
```

I still don't see why the original approach did not work though.